# Парсинг JSON файла идет не по плану

Tags: swift, swiftui

Нашел хороший api для конвертора валют. Хотел приступить к работе с ним, как вдруг заметил неладное:

```
  "base": "USD",
  "results": {
    "AED": 3.67291,
    "AFN": 95.08966,
    "ALL": 106.12942,
    "AMD": 480.86904,
    "ANG": 1.78826,
    "AOA": 527.28799,
// И так далее...
```

Как достать параметр base я понимаю:

```
struct Price: Codable {
    var base: String
    var results: [String:Double]
}

typealias Currency = [CurrencyData]
```

```
 class ContentModel: ObservableObject {
    
     @Published var base: String
     
    
     
     init() {
         fetchdata { (currency) in
             switch currency {
             case .success(let currency):
                 currency.forEach { (c) in
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.base.append(c.base)
                }
             }
             case(.failure(let error)):
                 print("Unable to featch the currencies data", error)
         }
     }
}

     func fetchdata(completion: @escaping (Result<Currency,Error>) -> ()) {
         guard let url = URL(string: "https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json") else { return }
         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responce, error in
             if let error = error {
                 completion(.failure(error))
                 return
             }
             
             guard let safeData = data else { return }
             
             do {
                 let currency = try JSONDecoder().decode(Currency.self, from: safeData)
                 completion(.success(currency))
             }
             catch {
                 completion(.failure(error))
             }
         }
         .resume()
     }
 }
```

Как мне использовать в View кодировки и их стоимость? Я хочу сделать Picker с кодами валют, но не знаю как получить необходимые мне данные. Возможно использовать альтернативный метод парсинга данных?

Answer (score 0):

1. Разделите по запятым
2. Разделите полученное по двоеточиям
3. Где первый символ двойные кавычки - удалите кавычки и используйте как string
4. Где первый символ пробел - удалите пробел и используйте как float